# Which of the following interesections is non-empty?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $P_1$ be the set of all primes $\{2,3,5,7,...\}$ and for each $n$, define $P_n$ to be the set of all prime multiples of $n$, i.e. $\{2n, 3n, 5n, 7n, . . .\}$. Which of the following interesections is non-empty?
>
> (a) $P_1 \cap P_{23}$ (b) $P_7 \cap P_{21}$ (c) $P_{12} \cap P_{20}$ (d) $P_{20} \cap P_{24}$ (e) $P_5 \cap P_{25}$

I don't know how to approach this and the hint in the solution doesn't make sense to me. The hint says "Count the number of prime factors. $P_1$ will always have exactly one while $P_{23}$ will always have two"

I mean, $P_{23}$ isn't even a number, what are its "prime factors"...

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Just to be clear, $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @ZirconCode Yes.

Comment: I believe the hint implies that all numbers in $P_{23}$ will have precisely two prime factors since 23 is a prime, the factors will be 23 and the prime multiplied by such. For something like $P_{12}$ you could try taking a part the 12 and see where it takes you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element of set $P_n$ can be represented as multiplication of some number of primes. In case of $P_{23}$ it will be multiplications of each prime on $23$. In case of $P_{24}$ it will be multiplications on $2^33$ and so on.

Back to the question, for given intersections to be non-empty, there should be no more than one prime factor not in common.

$(a) 1^1 \text{ and } 23^1$ +

$(b) 7^1 \text{ and } 3^17^1$ +

$(c) 2^23^1 \text{ and } 2^25^1$ +

$(d) 2^25^1 \text{ and } 2^33^1$ -

$(e) 5^1 \text{ and } 5^2$ +